# I don't know how to search for a file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I started learning to write scripts. Today I want to create a script which will show the directory where the file that I am asking for is.
The problem is that I can't "enter" the directory and search for the file.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a directory name..."
read directory
echo "enter a file name..."
read file
find -type d -name "$directory"
if [ -f ./$file ]
then
cat $file
else
echo "$file does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Firstly, don't post images of text. Paste the text using the code blocks. Second, the line `if [ -f ./$file ]` is looking for the file in the current working directory. Unless the file exists in the current working directory, it's going to return `$file does not exist`. Lastly, what do you mean by `I can't "enter" the directory and search for the file.`?

Comment: I mean, I want to check directory to see if there is a file, which I am looking for.

Comment: A way I often use is `ls some_dir/* | grep myfile`

Comment: Then you need to change the code so that it verifies that the file exists in the directory that was entered and not in the current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p 'enter a dir name >>> ' dir
read -p 'enter a filename >>> ' file
res="$(find "$dir" -name "$file")"
if [[ $res ]]; then
    cat "$res" # could be multiple same filename for different dirs
else
    echo >&2 "file $file doesn't exists in dir $dir"
fi
```